# In Russian, how do you say "she’s at it again"?

Tags: выражения

> Anna... she's **at it** **again** (doing something / with something)?
>
> Anna **fait** encore **des siennes** ?

We colloquially use these expressions in English and French when we catch someone (with a bit of a disobedient / mischievous / reckless  streak) once again  doing something you disapprove of.

> **Опять** Анна?
>
> **Опять** она?

I don't suppose this is sufficient as an equivalent, is it? How do you commonly express this "she's at it again, doing ...?" idea in Russian?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Она опять в своём репертуаре.
>
> Она опять / Опять она <sup>*greater annoyance*</sup> взялась за старое / за своё.
>
> Она опять / Опять она взялась за .....

Answer (score 3):

And there is also a saying/idiom:

> опять двадцать пять

Answer (score 1):

Yet another set of expressions is constructed with "снова". "[Он/она/они] снова [берутся] за старое", "[Он/она/они] снова за своё".

Both sets of expressions may be contracted in conversation: "(Ну) снова она!.."; "(Ну) опять она!.." -- implying she's "at it again".

Also, there exists a colloquial phrase (which you may encounter), the meaning of which I personally don't understand, it might just occur to be a conversational-space-filler: "Не опять, а снова" -- said in a quasi-ritual response to somebody saying "опять".